# Cython undefined symbol with c wrapper

Tags: cython

I am trying to expose c code to cython and am running into "undefined symbol" errors when trying to use functions defined in my c file from another cython module.
Functions defined in my h files and functions using a manual wrapper work without a problem.

Basically the same case as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685057/undefined-symbol-when-importing-a-cython-module-making-use-of-another-cython-mod) but the solution (Linking against the library) isn't satisfactory for me.
I assume i am missing something in the `setup.py` script ?

---

Minimized example of my case:

**foo.h**

```c
int source_func(void);

inline int header_func(void){
    return 1;
}
```

**foo.c**

```c
#include "foo.h"

int source_func(void){
    return 2;
}
```

---

**foo_wrapper.pxd**

```
cdef extern from "foo.h":
    int source_func()
    int header_func()

cdef source_func_wrapper()
```

**foo_wrapper.pyx**

```
cdef source_func_wrapper():
    return source_func()
```

---

The cython module i want to use the functions in:
**test_lib.pyx**

```
cimport foo_wrapper

def do_it():
    print "header func"
    print foo_wrapper.header_func() # ok
    print "source func wrapped"
    print foo_wrapper.source_func_wrapper() # ok    
    print "source func"
    print foo_wrapper.source_func() # undefined symbol: source_func
```

---

**setup.py** build both `foo_wrapper` and `test_lib`

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

# setup wrapper
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize([
        Extension("foo_wrapper", ["foo_wrapper.pyx", "foo.c"])
    ])
)

# setup test module 
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize([
        Extension("test_lib", ["test_lib.pyx"])
    ])
)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 3 different types of function in `foo_wrapper`:

1. `source_func_wrapper` is a python-function and python run-time handles the calling of this function.
2. `header_func` is an inline-function which is used at compile time, so its definition/machine code is not needed later on.
3. `source_func` on the other hand must be handled by static (this is the case in `foo_wrapper`) or dynamic (I assume this is your wish for `test_lib`) linker.

Further down I'll try to explain, why the setup doesn't not work out of the box, but fist I would like to introduce two (at least in my opinion) best alternatives :

**A:**  avoid this problem altogether. Your `foo_wrapper` wraps c-functions from `foo.h`. That means every other module **should** use these wrapper-functions. If everyone just can access the functionality directly -  this makes the whole wrapper kind of obsolete. Hide the `foo.h` interface in your `pyx-file:

```
#foo_wrapper.pdx
cdef source_func_wrapper()
cdef header_func_wrapper()


#foo_wrapper.pyx
cdef extern from "foo.h":
    int source_func()
    int header_func()

cdef source_func_wrapper():
    return source_func()
cdef header_func_wrapper():
```

**B:** It might be valid to want to use the foo-functionality directly via c-functions. In this case we should use the same strategy as cython with `stdc++`-library: `foo.cpp` should become a shared library and there should be only a `foo.pdx`-file (no pyx!) which can be imported via `cimport` wherever needed. Additionally, `libfoo.so` should then be added as dependency to both `foo_wrapper` and `test_lib`.

However, approach **B** means more hustle - you need to put `libfoo.so` somewhere the dynamic loader can find it...

---

**Other alternatives:**

As we will see, there are a lot of ways to get `foo_wrapper`+`test_lib` to work. First, let's see in more detail, how loading of dynamic libraries works in python.

We start out by taking a look at the `test_lib.so` at hand:

```
>>> nm test_lib.so --undefined
....
   U PyXXXXX
   U source_func
```

there are a lot of undefined symbols  most of which start with `Py` and will be provided by a python executable during the runtime. But also there is our evildoer - `source_func`.

Now, we start python via

```
LD_DEBUG=libs,files,symbols python
```

and load our extension via `import test_lib`. In the triggered debug -trace we can see the following:

```
>>>>: file=./test_lib.so [0];  dynamically loaded by python [0]
```

python loads `test_lib.so` via `dlopen` and starts to look-up/resolve the undefined symbols from `test_lib.so`:

```
>>>>:  symbol=PyExc_RuntimeError;  lookup in file=python [0]
>>>>:  symbol=PyExc_TypeError;  lookup in file=python [0]
```

these python symbols are found pretty quickly - they are all defined in the python-executable - the first place dynamic linker looks at (if this executable was linked with `-Wl,-export-dynamic`). But it is different with `source_func`:

```
 >>>>: symbol=source_func;  lookup in file=python [0]
 >>>>: symbol=source_func;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 [0]
  ...
 >>>>: symbol=source_func;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
 >>>>:  ./test_lib.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: source_func (fatal)
```

So after looking up all loaded shared libraries the symbol is not found and we have to abort. The fun fact is, that `foo_wrapper` is not yet loaded, so the `source_func` cannot be looked up there (it would be loaded in the next step as dependency of `test_lib` by python).

What happens if we start python with preloaded `foo_wrapper.so`?

```
  LD_DEBUG=libs,files,symbols LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/foo_wrapper.so python
```

this time, calling `import test_lib` succeed, because preloaded `foo_wrapper` is the first place the dynamic loader looks up the symbols (after the python-executable):

```
  >>>>: symbol=source_func;  lookup in file=python [0]
  >>>>: symbol=source_func;  lookup in file=/home/ed/python_stuff/cython/two/foo_wrapper.so [0]
```

But how does it work, when `foo_wrapper.so` is not preloaded? First let's add `foo_wrapper.so` as library to our setup of `test_lib`:

```
ext_modules = cythonize([
    Extension("test_lib", ["test_lib.pyx"], 
              libraries=[':foo_wrapper.so'], 
              library_dirs=['.'],
    )])
```

this would lead to the following linker command:

```
 gcc ... test_lib.o -L. -l:foo_wrapper.so -o test_lib.so
```

If we now look up the symbols, so we see no difference:

```
>>> nm test_lib.so --undefined
....
   U PyXXXXX
   U source_func
```

`source_func` is still undefined! So what is the advantage of linking against the shared library? The difference is, that now `foo_wrapper.so` is listed as needed in for `test_lib.so`:

```
>>>> readelf -d test_lib.so| grep NEEDED
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [foo_wrapper.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

`ld` does not link, this is a job of the dynamic linker, but it does a dry run and help dynamic linker by noting, that `foo_wrapper.so` is needed in order to resolve the symbols, so it must be loaded before the search of the symbols starts. However, it does not explicitly say, that the symbol `source_func` must be looked in `foo_wrapper.so` - we could actually find it and use it anywhere.

Lets start python again, this time without preloading:

```
  >>>> LD_DEBUG=libs,files,symbols python
  >>>> import test_lib
  ....
  >>>> file=./test_lib.so [0];  dynamically loaded by python [0]....
  >>>> file=foo_wrapper.so [0];  needed by ./test_lib.so [0]
  >>>> find library=foo_wrapper.so [0]; searching
  >>>> search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
  .....
  >>>> `foo_wrapper.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

Ok, now the dynamic linker knows, it has to find `foo_wrapper.so` but it is nowhere in the path, so we get an error message.

We have to tell dynamic linker where to look for the shared libraries. There is a lot of ways, one of them is to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
 LD_DEBUG=libs,symbols,files LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. python
 >>>> import test_lib
 ....
 >>>> find library=foo_wrapper.so [0]; searching
 >>>> search path=./tls/x86_64:./tls:./x86_64:.     (LD_LIBRARY_PATH) 
 >>>> ...
 >>>> trying file=./foo_wrapper.so
 >>>> file=foo_wrapper.so [0];  generating link map
```

This time `foo_wrapper.so` is found (dynamic loader looked at places hinted at by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), loaded and then used for resolving the undefined symbols in `test_lib.so`.

But what is the difference, if `runtime_library_dirs`-setup argument is used?

```
 ext_modules = cythonize([
    Extension("test_lib", ["test_lib.pyx"], 
              libraries=[':foo_wrapper.so'], 
              library_dirs=['.'],               
              runtime_library_dirs=['.']
             )
])
```

and now calling

```
 LD_DEBUG=libs,symbols,files python
 >>>> import test_lib
 ....
 >>>> file=foo_wrapper.so [0];  needed by ./test_lib.so [0]
 >>>> find library=foo_wrapper.so [0]; searching
 >>>> search path=./tls/x86_64:./tls:./x86_64:.     (RPATH from file ./test_lib.so)
 >>>>     trying file=./foo_wrapper.so
 >>>>   file=foo_wrapper.so [0];  generating link map
```

`foo_wrapper.so` is found on a so called `RPATH` even if not set via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. We can see this `RPATH` being inserted by the static linker:

```
  >>>> readelf -d test_lib.so | grep RPATH
        0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [.]
```

however this is the path relative to the current working directory, which is most of the time not what is wanted. One should pass an absolute path or use

```
   ext_modules = cythonize([
              Extension("test_lib", ["test_lib.pyx"], 
              libraries=[':foo_wrapper.so'],
              library_dirs=['.'],                   
              extra_link_args=["-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN/."] #rather than runtime_library_dirs
             )
])
```

to make the path relative to current location (which can change for example through copying/moving) of the resulting`shared library. readelf` shows now:

```
>>>> readelf -d test_lib.so | grep RPATH
     0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN/.]
```

which means the needed shared library will be searched relatively to the path of the loaded shared library, i.e `test_lib.so`.

That is also how your setup should be, if you would like to reuse the symbols from `foo_wrapper.so` which I do not advocate.

---

There are however some possibilities to use the libraries you have already built.

Let's go back to original setup. What happens if we first import `foo_wrapper` (as a kind of preload) and only then `test_lib`? I.e.:

```
 >>>> import foo_wrapper
 >>>>> import test_lib
```

This doesn't work out of the box. But why? Obviously, the loaded symbols from `foo_wrapper` are not visible to other libraries. Python uses `dlopen` for dynamical loading of shared libraries, and as explained in [this good article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=22435), there are some different strategies possible. We can use

```
 >>>> import sys
 >>>> sys.getdlopenflags() 
 >>>> 2
```

to see which flags are set. `2` means `RTLD_NOW`, which means that the symbols are resolved directly upon the loading of the shared library. We need to OR flag with`RTLD_GLOBAL=256` to make the symbols visible globally/outside of the dynamically loaded library.

```
>>> import sys; import ctypes;
>>> sys.setdlopenflags(sys.getdlopenflags()| ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
>>> import foo_wrapper
>>> import test_lib
```

and it works, our debug trace shows:

```
>>> symbol=source_func;  lookup in file=./foo_wrapper.so [0]
>>> file=./foo_wrapper.so [0];  needed by ./test_lib.so [0] (relocation dependency)
```

Another interesting detail: `foo_wrapper.so` is loaded once, because python does not load a module twice via import `foo_wrapper`. But even if it would be opened twice, it would be only once in the memory (the second read only increases the reference count of the shared library).

But now with won insight we could even go further:

```
 >>>> import sys;
 >>>> sys.setdlopenflags(1|256)#RTLD_LAZY+RTLD_GLOBAL
 >>>> import test_lib
 >>>> test_lib.do_it()
 >>>> ... it works! ....
```

Why this? `RTLD_LAZY` means that the symbols are resolved not directly upon the loading but when they are used for the first time. But before the first usage (`test_lib.do_it()`), `foo_wrapper` is loaded (import inside of `test_lib` module) and due to `RTLD_GLOBAL` its symbols can be used for resolving later on.

If we don't use `RTLD_GLOBAL`, the failure comes only when we call `test_lib.do_it()`, because the needed symbols from `foo_wrapper` are not seen globally in this case.

---

To the question, why it is not such a great idea just to link both modules `foo_wrapper` and `test_lib` against `foo.cpp`: Singletons, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361981/cant-redirect-error-stream-from-cython/45372319#45372319).

Comment: RE: "If everyeveryone just can access the functionality directly - this makes the whole wrapper obsolete": This is exactly what i plan to do though. cdefed classes for the common cases for py and cython, but still be able to use the core lib functions from cython if required. IMHO that is a valid use case.

Comment: I am a bit irritated that i have to do it this way tbh. Cython embeds my `foo.c` code, why can't i just call it like i can call cdefed functions (which are also declared in a pxd -> converted to .h and defined in pyx -> converted to .c file). Basically the exact same scenario or what am i missing here ?

Comment: @SleepProgger probably "obsolete" and "muddy design" is too strong language, there is some overhead involved in calling functions via wrapper so one may want to have direct C-calls.

Comment: Sorry, i though i already accepted your answer. Thank you for the detailed information. Another way if one only wants to expose some specific functions is simply declaring function pointers in the pxd file and define them in the pyx file.