# Cython: avoid compiling all C/C++ files on each extension. Objective: distribute in PyPi

Tags: python, c++, cython, python-extensions

The Cython project I am currently working on includes some 20 C++ files that act as C++ implementation. On top I have built three Extension Modules written in Cython, each of them capturing different but interconnected functionalities of the C++ implementation. In order to wrap the required functionalities form C++ I used one single `.pxd` file that defines all the `cdef extern` blocks. Later on, the 3 `.pyx` files with the 3 Extension Modules (one Extension Module per .pyx file) cimport the `pxd` wrapper and add extra functionality.

Now, my objective is to pack the whole library and distribute it using PyPi. My problem arises when using setup.py: I don't know how to make the C++ code available for all Extension Modules. For development I have installed the C++ as a dynamic library in Linux, which clearly has a lot of portability issues. I am more than willing to export the C++ source code to be compiled locally (thus creating a source distribution using `python setup.py sdist`).

These are the approaches I've taken so far, all of them failed:

1. Including the C++ source files in the `sources` of all extensions. It compiles all the C++ files for each Extension. This creates multiple copies of global objects.
2. Including the C++ source files in the most important Extension and importing it always first. The other Extension modules throw `undefined symbol` errors because they don't have access to the C++ implementation.
3. Creating a 4th Extension module with the name of the Cython `.pxd` wrapper and importing it first. Same result as above (#2).

Any tips will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Tests 2 and 3 sound fine on the principle. There are many projects on PyPI that distribute C or C++ code that is built on the destination machine. For 2 and 3 however, you must not access the C++ code as "cdef extern" but by "cimporting" it as it is already available at the Cython level. Maybe that was the issue? For more help, we'd need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yeap, I'm accessing the C++ code by "cimporting". The only "cdef extern" blocks are located in the `.pxd` wrapper. Could you redirect me to any of those projects? I believe that a working example could help me gratly. So far I've tried checking on lxml, sciPy, spaCy and some others. I'll prepare an example otherwise.

Comment: For the specific case of accessing global variables, it is a bit harder to find examples actually. The simulation code [ESPResSo](https://github.com/espressomd/espresso) uses global variables, see `src/python/espressomd/globals.pxd` there. They use a more complex build procedure but for a simple C++ project that should not be an issue.

Comment: That problem is not uncommon when using cython. However, it seems as if a good answer is lacking here on SO. Probably adding a [mcve] would help to understand the problem better (the minimal-part is quite important though).

Comment: A somewhat related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655654/5769463, however it isn't concise enough too be of much use.

Comment: If your pxd-file has `cdef extern from header.h` using the functionality will result in going directly to C++-functionality and thus *.so-library is needed during linkage/run time. If you wrap the functionality in cdef-functions and expose only those wrappers in the pxd-file, you will not need the so-library directly it would be enough to cimport the wrapper-extension. However, not sure this could work for something more complex (classes) than simple functions.

Comment: When I face this issue, I just put all extensions into one to avoid the hassle... With time I got pretty good at muting the voice of the purist in my head, which screams every time I do it.

Comment: @ead How do you do that? Do you have any open source code I could have a look into? That was my first intention but I run into trouble and found everywhere people telling me to use one Extension per `.pyx` file!

Comment: I put them all into the same pyx-file. This is the part where the voice start screaming:)

Comment: Ugh, if I do that with 4000+ lines of code, the next developer touching my code is going to kill me

Comment: @ead I'm back with this old problem. Do you have any particular answers in SO that could point me in the right direction? I had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63875206/how-to-share-a-c-singleton-between-multiple-c-extensions but couldn't find a solution. I can prepare an example for my case otherwise

Comment: The approach from the linked answer is well suited for libraries with a very small public interface and works best with C rather than C++ (classes being kind of a problem). So the options I can thing of are either to distribute precompiled so/dll (which reduces the number of platforms for which the extension can be used) or to override `build_clib` to build shared libraries. My plan was to add a second answer, which describes `build_clib`-option in more detail, but haven't found the time yet. Here is a prototype for such solution: https://github.com/realead/commonso/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: @ead, I just found the Holy Grial you were hiding in your garden https://github.com/realead/solinks . Have you ever thought of writing a book about Cython?

Comment: One small extra question: I tried your approach from github.com/realead/commonso/blob/master/setup.py , and while it works perfectly in Linux (Ubuntu), it fails for Windows, complaining that it cannot find the `*.lib` file. Indeed, when compiling the shared `dll` library in windows, I only get a `dll` file, and not a `lib` file. You won't happen to know how to generate both the `dll` and the `lib` files, do you?

Comment: Note: Since this is getting extremely complex, once I get a working solution I will prepare a smaller example and post it at SO for further reference.

Comment: INFO: I ended up building it as a static library (much like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57673283/prevent-double-compilation-of-c-files-in-cython). Dynamic libraries need to be stored and found on all OS. I couldn't find a clean way to do this.