# Use Cython to wrap C/C++-program depending on multiple libraries

Tags: python, c++, c, cython, static-libraries

I have a large C/C++ project which I usually just build as a standalone executable. It also requires some libraries (system libraries like pthread, but also MKL from intel for example) which I specify when compiling the project.

Now, I want to use some functions from this project in Python. So my first plan was to simply build the project as a static library and then use that to write a cython wrapper. I.e.

1. Build the c project: `icc -c src/main.cpp .. options and stuff.. linking to all libraries needed .. -o main.o`
2. Create a static library (including the libraries I needed in step 1): `ar -rc libmain.a main.o ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a ... /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a ...`
3. I use the generated static library to build my cython wrapper
4. when I try to execute a test python script calling a random function from my C program I get this error `ImportError: /home/.../main.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: __kmpc_ok_to_fork`

It seems like I need to tell cython to link to the corresponding libraries again or something, but I'm not really sure how to resolve this.. Also I don't want the python project to be dependent on some special libraries that I have installed on my system (that's what I try to achieve by adding all the libraries in step 2), is this possible at all?

My setup.py looks like this

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os

os.environ["CC"] = "icc"
os.environ["CXX"] = "icc"
setup(
   ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("test", ["test.pyx"], language="c++",
                                  library_dirs=[r'.'], libraries=['main'])])
)
```

Comment: A quick search suggests that `__kmpc_ok_to_fork` is in `libiomp5`. Can you try adding "iomp5" to the libraries?

Comment: no, unfortunately the error still remains unchanged..

Comment: Also from adding all the libraries the resulting static library file is getting really huge (like almost 1Gb). There must be a smarter way to do this.. If I don't include the libraries and somehow manage to tell cython to do all the linking, will the -so file generated by cython be independent of all the libraries? Like could I still just copy it to a different machine?

Comment: The issue is, that the linker cannot use your static library. The correct way to create it is https://stackoverflow.com/a/50031940/5769463

Comment: But usually you don’t use static versions of libraries - this can lead to strange results (as ODR could be violated)

Comment: Ok I see. I first have to unpack the .a files.. But if creating a static library isn't the proper solution, how would you go about this?

Comment: This might be a possible solution (distributing needed shared libraries): https://stackoverflow.com/q/63804883/5769463

Comment: This is not entirely in the spirit of the question, but I highly recommend using pybind11 for Python/C++ bindings. https://github.com/pybind/pybind11

Answer (score 1):

Create a shared library (.so on linux). Python can only support dynamic or shared libraries. The linker is looking for a .so not a .a.

So your setup.py would be remain the same,

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os

os.environ["CC"] = "icc"
os.environ["CXX"] = "icc"
setup(
   ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("test", ["test.pyx"], language="c++",
                                  library_dirs=[r'.'], libraries=['main'])])
)
```

Related - [Using Cython To Link Python To A Shared Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993927/using-cython-to-link-python-to-a-shared-library).

Comment: Setup.py doesn’t look for libraries, it only passes names of the libraries to the linker, which will pick the static version (e.g. .a) if there is no shared version.

Comment: Yes setup.py does pass the name to the linker. Cythonize converts Cython to C. And Python can only work with C code that links with a shared library not a static one.

Comment: If static library was compiled with position independent code, there is no reason it cannot be used in a python-extension (and as said, setup.py does nothing to prevent that)

Comment: @ead I am a volunteer in CPython and I'm 99% sure that Python can't work with static library. The main point is if the code now works or not. And also notice I edited my answer to change setup.py to linker.

Comment: It is even possible to build a static library during the setup.py and use it in multiple extensions. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/57673781/5769463