# Missing symbol error after compiling a library that references another precompiled library

Tags: python, c++, linker, g++, cython

**tl;dr**: I'm trying to compile a .cpp file that references another compiled API (.so + .h files), and I get a missing symbol when I try to load it. Below is a simple example of how I created the modules, and all the steps that I made along the way. Help would be very appreciated.

**NOTE:** Before you decide to skip this question because you might know nothing about Cython, this is more of a linker/g++ question than a cython question, so please read to the end.

I'm trying to create a Cython module that wraps a precompiled C++ API library, and I get strange errors on importation to python. So I have made a simple example during which:

1. Compile a simple C++ library (.so + .h files)
2. Compile a simple Cython module that references it.
3. Load that module in Python to access the underlying C++ library.

First I have the following two files:

```cpp
// circle.h
#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H

class Circle {
public:
    Circle(float radius);
    float getDiameter() const;

private:
    float m_radius;
};

#endif // CIRCLE_H

//circle.cpp
#include "circle.h"

Circle::Circle(float radius) : m_radius(radius) {}

float Circle::getDiameter() const {
    return m_radius * 2.0f;
}
```

I compile these into `build/Circle.so` using the following commands:

```bash
mkdir -p build
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c circle.cpp -o build/Circle.o
g++ -shared build/Circle.o -o build/Circle.so
cp circle.h build/Circle.h
```

Now I turned to create my Cython module by creating the following file named `example.pyx`:

```
# distutils: language = c++

cdef extern from "build/Circle.h":
    cdef cppclass Circle:
        Circle(float radius)
        float getDiameter()

cdef class PyCircle:
    cdef Circle* c_circle

    def __cinit__(self, float radius):
        self.c_circle = new Circle(radius)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.c_circle

    def getDiameter(self):
        return self.c_circle.getDiameter()
```

Then I ran `cythonize -i example.pyx` and got two files in the root directory: `example.cpp` (a Cython-generated source file) & `example.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. I renamed the latter to `example.so`  and tried to import it from a python (`import example`), and I get the following error:

> ImportError: example.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK6Circle11getDiameterEv

So I looked into the aforecompiled (that's almost a word) module `Circle.so` using the command `nm -D build/Circle.so | grep Diameter`, and indeed I saw that the missing symbol resides inside that module:

> 0000000000001110 T _ZNK6Circle11getDiameterEv

So I figured "there must be some problem with the linker. I know! Let's compile that auto-generated .cpp source code and link to that library!". So I did the following:

1. Ran `g++ -O2 -fPIC -c example.cpp -I /usr/include/python3.9 -I build/Circle.h`
2. Renamed `build/Circle.so` to `libCircle.so`
3. Ran `g++ -shared example.o -Lbuild -lCircle -o example.so`
4. Ran `import example` in the python console and I got the same error.

What am I doing wrong? How come that symbol is not loaded?

Comment: Using [demangler.com](http://demangler.com/), I can prettify your undefined symbol to `Circle::getDiameter() const`.  Does that help?

Comment: When I try the second set of steps locally (after cleaning up all the objects and shared libraries), I get `ImportError: libCircle.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, not `undefined symbol: _ZNK6Circle11getDiameterEv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem is that Cython doesn't know about `circle.cpp` and the definitions within. There are a couple ways to fix this, depending on the final use case. The first two require `circle.cpp` to build the Cython module, while the third just needs the shared library and headers.

#### Directly include `circle.cpp` ([docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#add-public-attributes))

You can tell Cython about the `circle.cpp` file with a `cdef extern from` block, which it will `#include` from the generated `example.cpp` file:

```
cdef extern from "circle.cpp":
    pass
```

#### Statically link with `circle.cpp` ([docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html#static-linking))

Add a directive at the top of `example.pyx` that tells cythonize to build `circle.cpp` and statically link it into `example.so`:

```
# distutils: sources = circle.cpp
```

#### Dynamically link with `libCircle.so` ([docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html#dynamic-linking))

Add some directives to `example.pyx`, which essentially add `-Lbuild -lCircle` to the linker invocation:

```
# distutils: library_dirs = build
# distutils: libraries = Circle
```

You'll need to make sure `libCircle.so` is somewhere that the dynamic linker knows about: either install it, add the build directory to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or add an [`rpath`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) entry to resolve it relative to `example.so`.

Also see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655654/5769463) for a very detailed breakdown of how dynamic library loading works in Cython.

Comment: A great answer. That last options did the trick. Also, I added `# distutils: extra_link_args = -Wl,-rpath=build` for that to work without the environment variable.. Thanks!